# (PHPMyAdmin) Как добавить столбец?

Tags: php, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Имеется столбец с именем пользователя, паролем, датой регистрации и идентификатором. Как мне добавить ещё один столбик с записью "О себе" и с путём к аватарке? Неужели мне придётся удалить таблицу и переделать его?

Comment: пароли в базе не храните ...

Comment: А где, если не на базе?

Comment: Нигде. Хранится соль и хэш от пароля и соли для проверки при входе. Если кто-то упрет базу паролей не узнает.

Comment: Ты же понимаешь, что хэшами уже ничего не спрячешь? Хакеры всё равно могут расшифровать хэши и получить доступ к паролям.

Comment: @Endivine Может вы и правы, используйте sha256 + соль, таким образом хотябы осложните им задачу))

Comment: Да уж, как говорят, нужно не просто сделать взлом невозможным, а невыгодным)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Сначала необходимо найти из списка таблиц искомую и в её строке нажать на кнопку структура**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Далее необходимо задать количество добавляемых столбцов и место их расположения в списке. После нажатия кнопки вперед сделать тоже самое, что и при создании таблицы(заполнить параметры поля)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Эту проблему можно осуществить благодаря SQL запросу:

ALTER TABLE *<Название таблицы>* ADD *<Название столбца>* VARCHAR (20);

Comment: Серьезно ? В phpmyadmin ? А через "Структуру" таблицы, нажав 1 кнопку - религия не позволяет ?

Comment: Я уже нашёл ответ на свой вопрос и не обязательно так гневно отвечать.